# How to solve this python permission error about reading file name

Tags: python, loadimage

I'm trying to read file name using python3 with keras, tensorflow-gpu.
Code is here.
I omitted some of the code.

```
imgdir_train = './trainval_Animals/train'
imgdir_test = './trainval_Animals/val'


    for eachimg in imgs:
        if eachimg[0] == '.':
            continue

        img_path = classpath+'/'+eachimg
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
        feature = model.predict(x)

        features_all[idx, :] = feature
        labels_all.append(eachclass)
        images_all.append(eachimg)
        idx += 1
```

Load_img does not properly fetch the file path.
Error is here.

```
File "feature_extract.py", line 126, in <module>
    main()
  File "feature_extract.py", line 101, in main
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
  File "C:\Users\dunghwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 498, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(path)
  File "C:\Users\dunghwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2634, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './trainval_Animals/val/A_ant'
```

Even if I specify the path correctly, a permission error occurs.
What should I do..?

Comment: The error description is very clear. You don't have permissions to read `A_ant` file. Maybe it belongs to another user?

Comment: Set proper permissions within the OS.

Comment: Is the file by any chance **opened**?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans  I have downloaded the provided data to my computer and it is in use. Is this a different user?

Comment: (Try to reboot.....)

Comment: @김정화 were you able to solve this?

Comment: @user5173426 No...  :( I can't this problem in windows10, so I changed my OS linux64.. and then this error doesn't appear anymore.. I don't understand why this error was happened.

Comment: @김정화 that's weird. Glad you're past the problem, if you think you are done with it you may accept the answer if it helped.